# Android wifi re-connect if it can not ping

Tags: android, wifi

Hi is there a wifi manager that will,

Connect to my preferred access point if it is in range and then try to reach the net every 30 seconds and if it can not reach the net, toggle wifi.

I have a wibro 4g modem and it drops the wifi connection on its end but Android still thinks it has a connection.

This may also be Android putting the wifi to sleep. So another answer is, how could I get 2.23 to never put the wifi to sleep? I have of course set this in settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could I get 2.23 to never put the wifi to sleep?

Have you tried WIFI-LOCK? This will prevent it from sleeping.

```
WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
    .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

wifiLock.acquire();
```